# How to enable other websites to embed my website's content using only content link?

Tags: html, embed, meta-tags, embedded-resource

I have been spending my past week on the Internet to find at least one hint about it. There are no tutorials or even SO questions available. What I am trying to find is that when some website uses some library like oEmbed to embed content of other websites on their website, they fetch embed code from its link. For example, when you post a YouTube link on Facebook or other social networks, they automatically fetch their embed code. I know how to fetch embed code but what I don't know is how to provide embed code that can be fetched by other websites by using a link of my website's content?

I want that my article should be embedded in some special way. Not like the default layout of that website. So is there any META tag or something in HTML where I can put embed code for other websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Alvaro Montoro, I searched on the Internet about how to become an oembed provider. Following are the links I found:

https://timnash.co.uk/becoming-oembed-provider/

http://freear.org.uk/content/5-steps-being-oembed-provider

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want is possible. You can use special meta-tags that specific sites (e.g.: Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin) will interpret, and that will help you customize the share a little (still using the "host site" style). But as far as I know, there's nothing you can do to provide style/code of your own.

And it makes sense from a security point of view: embedding external code from an unknown source is potentially dangerous and no site would/should allow you to do it. Even if they do allow it, they should pre-process the code and sanitize it (adapting your style/code to their style/code) to prevent possible threats.

Comment: But how [oEmbed](http://oembed.com/) automatically detects the media on any site and embeds it?

Comment: (From what I've read online in the last 15-20 minutes) oEmbed is only an open format/specification of the data that needs to be returned. oEmbed knows nothing and detects nothing; the provider decides if they want to implement an oEmbed service and how to do so. Not all web sites will have it, and not all web sites that have it will return the same parameters for a similar request. If you want your web site to implement oEmbed, you will have to create the service yourself. If you want to read oEmbed data from Web sites, there are some nice libraries on the oEmbed home Web site.

Comment: Thanks for this nice explanation. Your suggestion gave me a hint about what to search on the Internet. I found some links. I am posting it as a answer mentioning you and a +1 to you.

Answer (score -3):

You may want to use the CSS !important directive.

http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Have you read the description of the question? It's not about CSS.